# Preview the folder browser of a printout selection on excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that prints a selection into pdf. And I would really like to set the path where it has to be saved, and maybe even the name of the file, so when the person clicks on the button, it shows the folder browser already on the path I want.

The code I have saves the pdf automatically on the path I want, but it doesn´t show the folder browser.

I want to display the folder browser, and before saving automatically, I want to confirm in the folder browser, so the user is sure that everything worked and it´s okay.

Is that possible?

My code:

```
Sub PDF()
'
' PDF Macro
' PDF
'

'
    Sheets("CARTA").Select
    Range("A1:H29").Select
    Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:="K:\sinistro\SINISTRO MASS CONSUMER\REGULAÇÃO GARANTIA ESTENDIDA\03 - Confirmação de troca\teste.pdf"
    Sheets("MENU2").Select
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```vb
Sub PDF()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select folder to print out the file"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\test\" ' your initial path
        If .Show = -1 Then
            FNAME = .SelectedItems(1) & "\teste.pdf"
            With Sheets("CARTA")
                PrintArea = .PageSetup.PrintArea                ' save the previous print area
                .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("A1:H29").Address ' set the print area for the target range
                .ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, FNAME
                .PageSetup.PrintArea = PrintArea                ' restore the previous print area
            End With
            Sheets("MENU2").Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```